# Re-Rendering Angular component

Tags: angular, components

I have the below stackblitz whenever I change the value of the boolean var I want the component to be rerendered how can I achieve that?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8rwqba?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `[checked]` instead of `[value]` :

```html
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="test1"/>test1 - {{test1}}
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="test2"/>test2 - {{test2}}
```

Comment: but I think based on the value the component is shown or hidden lets say a component is hidden than I click to show it I want the component to be recompiled

Comment: angular have a lifecycle system : https://itnext.io/understanding-angular-life-cycle-hooks-91616f8946e3, so in this case you just have to use a *ngIf based on the input value (test1 or test2 here) and angular will handle that for you :).

Sometimes (really rarely in specific cases), Angular is not re-rendering the data as you expect, and you can force it by using detectChanges() method of ChangeDetectorRef service